# Can I delete the DLC after I'm done playing it?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-360

I'm running out of space on my 360 hard drive and need to clear up some space. My Mass Effect 3 install is eating up alot of space on my drive. I've played through all of the DLC but haven't finished the game. Since I finished these add on missions; can I delete their DLC from my drive? I'm pretty sure I can't delete From Ashes since it contains a playable character; but how about the rest (Leviathan, Citadel)? If I delete them, will the game break on me or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the ME3 DLCs offers additional things that carry on beyond the DLC itself.  Most of these are in the form of:

- Bonus power of some kind
- War Assets
- Bonus weapons, mods, and armor (The citadel DLC in particular adds a sweet pistol with massive head shot bonus as well as an assault rifle that doesn't require ammo.  It also adds the best armor in the game).
- Mini games (Mostly citadel DLC)

I don't think the game would break, but you'd be missing out.  In short, I wouldn't recommend deleting any DLCs until your game is complete.

Comment: I'm not completely sure on this - not specifically to the Xbox but in Mass Effect 2 the save files contained DLC specific data, so removing the DLCs would invalidate your save files until you reinstalled them. I've never tried it in ME3 but I would expect it to be the same